# Method won't change global variable value

Tags: java, android

I tried to extract value from inner method by global variable, but i cant access to any global variable from method, just i want to get the value from method to onCreate method!

Get value from inner method to another.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseFirestore db;
    //TextView  txtv;

    double tt = 55d;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        //txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);


            //should print value of 'lat' >> 33
            //but it print original value of tt >> 55
            // I just want value of variable 'lat' here
          System.out.println(ReadSingleContact(1));

    }

    public double ReadSingleContact(int x ) {
        String num = Integer.toString(x);
        DocumentReference contact = db.collection("MAPS").document(num);
        contact.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task ) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                    /*
                    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder("");
                    data.append("name: ").append(doc.getString("name"));
                    data.append("\nlatitude: ").append(doc.getString("latitude"));
                    data.append("\nlongtude: ").append(doc.getString("longtude"));

                    */
                    GeoPoint geoPoint = doc.getGeoPoint("latitude");
                    final double lat = geoPoint.getLatitude();
                    final double lng = geoPoint.getLongitude();

                    //let say lat = 33
                    tt = lat;

                }
            }
        });
        return tt;
    }

}
```

no syntax error, just variable 'tt' dose not change ?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I expected 22.0 but it still 0.0 !!!

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: I tried it, result will be value of lat and value of lng ,, but in text view, i did not want that, i need value of variable “lat” to use it in another method, if you know any way to do this please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** - If you intent to use the function in multiple places and need to use the result, then you'll need to get the result from the asynchronous call using a callback (infact, you're already using a callback for `contact.get()`). You'll need to refactor your code along the following lines.

Create a java file for the interface.

```
public interface CustomCallback {
    void onComplete(double lat, double lng);
}
```

Use the interface as an argument to your function, call the `onComplete` after you get the values of `lat` & `lng`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    TextView  txtv;
    double tt ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        //txtv.setText(ReadSingleContact(1)+"A");
        //Here you can call the function and implement the interface method that'll get called once the values for lat & lng are calculated
        ReadSingleContact(1, new CustomCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(double lat, double lng) {
                //here you can implement your required code
                //which can be changed based on what calls this method
                txtv.setText(lat+"A");
                //P.S - At this point, the value of tt would have been changed, since the `onComplete` method gets called after the value of tt is changed.
            }
        });
    }
    public void ReadSingleContact(int x, CustomCallback customCallback) {
        String num = Integer.toString(x);
        DocumentReference contact = db.collection("MAPS").document(num);
        contact.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task ) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                    /*
                    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder("");
                    data.append("name: ").append(doc.getString("name"));
                    data.append("\nlatitude: ").append(doc.getString("latitude"));
                    data.append("\nlongtude: ").append(doc.getString("longtude"));
                    */
                    GeoPoint geoPoint = doc.getGeoPoint("latitude");
                    double lat = geoPoint.getLatitude();
                    double lng = geoPoint.getLongitude();
                    tt = 22;
                    //Call customCallback.onComplete at the end
                    if (customCallback != null) {
                        customCallback.onComplete(lat,lng);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

The `contact.get()` is an asynchronous call, so `tt = 22;` will likely only occur after `return tt;`. If you simply want to set the latitude and longitude value in the textview, then do so in the callback.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    TextView  txtv;
    double tt ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        //txtv.setText(ReadSingleContact(1)+"A");
    }
    public double ReadSingleContact(int x ) {
        String num = Integer.toString(x);
        DocumentReference contact = db.collection("MAPS").document(num);
        contact.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task ) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                    /*
                    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder("");
                    data.append("name: ").append(doc.getString("name"));
                    data.append("\nlatitude: ").append(doc.getString("latitude"));
                    data.append("\nlongtude: ").append(doc.getString("longtude"));

                    */
                    GeoPoint geoPoint = doc.getGeoPoint("latitude");
                     double lat = geoPoint.getLatitude();
                    double lng = geoPoint.getLongitude();
                   //value dose not changed ??!
                    tt = 22;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                         void run() {
                             txtv.setText(tt+"A");
                             txtv.setText(lat+","+lng);
                         }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return tt;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, I know that text View will change to value of 'lat' and 'lng', but i didn't want that, I will simplify what i want: I just want method 'ReadSingleContact' to return value of 'lat' variable, because i need this value in another method 'onCreate', when i call  'ReadSingleContact' i need it to return value of variable 'lat' as double .

Comment: I edited the original  code, may simplify what i want.

Comment: You can't return the `lng` value in the function since the asynchronous call wouldn't have completed at that point of time. You could, however, implement a callback to update you in your `onCreate` when the asynchronous call completes. I've updated my answer. Check and mark the answer as correct if it works. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, It's Work :) -- Thank you very much Mr Chrisvin

Comment: Hi again :( now I can use lat and lng inside onCreate method but also inside the function itself, if I want to Get new lat and lng  by change the first argument of the function (1,2,3,4....) every number have different location (lat,lng), there is no way to get the value of lat or lng through a single variable of double function to return the value ? thanks

Comment: You can't return a value from a function that has an asynchronous call. Period. You could convert the asynchronous call into a synchronous call, but that would defeat the purpose and is usually a bad idea (since it might lead to cases where the UI thread gets blocked or your app crashes since you're making network calls on the main thread).

Comment: mmmm, Let's go back to start, I need a method to read different geopoints from firebase-firestore to use it as marks on maps, that is all what i want, can you help me? or can you tell me search about something to do ? thank you very much

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what you actually need, could you update your question code to show what you require? If you require to send an array of points and get an array of (lat,lng), then wrap the lat & lng values as a pair in an `ArrayList` and pass that in the callback function(you'll need to change the interface appropriately).